# Как наиболее оптимально скрыть элемент с определённым значением data-атрибута?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется следующий код:

```js
let customerFields = $('.form-group').toArray();

$.each(customerFields, function(index, field) {
 let idRow = $(field).attr('data-property-id-row');

 if (idRow == "10" || idRow == "13" || idRow == "15") {
  $(field).hide();
 }
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="1">1</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="2">2</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="3">3</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="4">4</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="15">15</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="10">10</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="13">13</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="18">18</div>
```

Здесь скрываются элементы с определенным значением data-property-id-row. В настоящий момент скрытие реализовано через несколько "или". Есть ли более короткий путь реализации скрытия элементов, и если да, то какой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно сократить их в такой способ. Создаем массив вариантов и в случае, если значение есть в этом массиве, тогда функция вернет номер позиции в массиве (>=0), в противном случае вернет -1.

```
if (~['10', '13', '15'].indexOf(idRow)) {
```

Или можно использовать немного новее метод:

```
if (['10', '13', '15'].includes(idRow)) {
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помогло!

Comment: Нема за что ;-)

Answer (score 3):

includes() можно попробовать

```js
let customerFields = $('.form-group').toArray();

$.each(customerFields, function(index, field) {
 let idRow = $(field).attr('data-property-id-row');

 if (['10','13','15'].includes(idRow)) {
  $(field).hide();
 }
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="1">1</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="2">2</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="3">3</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="4">4</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="15">15</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="10">10</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="13">13</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="18">18</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Одной строкой.

```js
$('[data-property-id-row="10"],[data-property-id-row="13"],[data-property-id-row="15"]').hide();
```

```css
.form-group {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="1">1</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="2">2</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="3">3</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="4">4</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="15">15</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="10">10</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="13">13</div>
<div class="form-group customer-field" data-property-id-row="18">18</div>
```